# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_0^\infty (1 + x/n)^{-n}x^{-1/n}dx= 1$ using DCT

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Prove that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty }  \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{dx}}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}}}}  = 1$ using dominated convergence theorem (DCT). By DCT we need to show $\left| {\frac{1}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}}}} \right| \le \phi (x)$ for some Lebesgue integral function $\phi(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$.

My attempt solved part of the problem on $[1,\infty)$. When $x\geq1$, we have $\frac{1}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}}} \le \frac{1}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}}}$.
Then ${(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n} = 1 + C_n^1\frac{x}{n} + C_n^2\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{n^2}}} + ... \le 1 + C_n^1\frac{x}{n} + C_n^2\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{n^2}}} = 1 + x + \frac{{n(n - 1)}}{{2{n^2}}}{x^2}$.

Since $\frac{{n(n - 1)}}{{2{n^2}}} \ge \frac{1}{4}$ when $n\ge2$, we get ${(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n} \ge 1 + x + \frac{{{x^2}}}{4} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}}} \le \frac{1}{{1 + x + \frac{1}{4}{x^2}}}$ when $n\ge2$.

$\frac{1}{{1 + x + \frac{1}{4}{x^2}}}$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[1,\infty)$, then by dominated convergence theorem $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_1^\infty  {\frac{{dx}}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}}}}  = \int_1^\infty  {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{dx}}{{{{(1 + \frac{x}{n})}^n}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}}}}  = \int_1^\infty  { - {e^{ - x}}dx} $

But I cannot prove the limit and integration are exchangeable on $[0,1]$. Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: You know $\bigl(1+\frac{x}{n}\bigr)^n \geqslant 1$. Can you find a dominating function for $x^{-1/n}$ for $n \geqslant 2$?

Comment: If $0<x<1$ then $x^t$ is a _decreasing_ function of $t$...

Comment: Lemma $(9)$ [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/254a-supplement-3-the-gamma-function-and-the-functional-equation-optional/) should be enlightening.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I have figured it out with your help.